# Как сравнить несколько аргументов в одной строке без лишних повторений?

Tags: c++

Как сравнить несколько аргументов в одной строке без лишнего копирования, я буду сравнивать больше 2 аргументов, возможно их будет 5.

У меня есть пару аргументов например.

```
char A1 = 1, B2 = 2, C3 = 3, D4 = 4;
```

Я бы хотел это делать так

```
if (function == A1 || B2) {

 std::cout << A1 << " " << B2 << std::endl;

}
```

Но приходиться делать это так

```
if (function == A1 || function ==  B2) {

 std::cout << A1 << " " << B2 << std::endl;

}
```

Я бы не хотел каждый раз повторять **function ==**
Можно ли как то это упростить?

Или как вариант покажите как вы делаете это с enum, главное что бы код был минималистичный

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В вопросе упоминался `enum`. Если значения не большие, можно перейти к позициям битов:

```
int A1 = 1 << 1, B2 = 1 << 2, C3 = 1 << 3;

...
char bit = function << 3;
if ((bit & (A1 | B2 | C3)) != 0) {
    ...
}
```

`uint64_t` позволит работать с диапазоном `[0, 63]`. Нотация достаточно компактная и читабельная (для любителей С). С точки зрения скорости исполнения - это вообще одна инструкция процессора (ещё одна для `function << 3`, но можно работать сразу с величинами вида `1 << n_bit` без промежуточных преобразований).

Comment: Тоже крутое решение, спасибо

Comment: выбрал этот вариант

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename x_Value, typename... x_Args>
auto cmp(x_Value const & value, x_Args const &... args)
{
    return ((value == args) or ...);
}

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto a{3};
    auto b{5};
    auto c{3};
    auto d{6};
    assert(cmp(a, b, c, d));
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27template%3Ctypename+x_Value,+typename...+x_Args___%3E%0Aauto+cmp(x_Value+const+%26+value,+x_Args___+const+%26...+args___)%0A%7B%0A++++return+((value+%3D%3D+args___)+or+...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+a%7B3%7D%3B%0A++++auto+b%7B5%7D%3B%0A++++auto+c%7B3%7D%3B%0A++++auto+d%7B6%7D%3B%0A++++assert(cmp(a,+b,+c,+d))%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g121,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Стоит сказать, что в таком решении вычисление всех операндов будет происходить всегда, тогда как в случае простого `(a == b) or (a == c) || (a == d)` они будут вычисляться только при необходимости.

Comment: не понял куда тут вставлять условия `function`

Я пишу так `if (cmp(a, b, c, d))` он пишет что это true, хотя значения там разные у всех

Comment: А разобрался первый аргумент должен быть function как я понял

Comment: Если все значения разные, то будет `false` https://godbolt.org/z/zEfrqPsnn

Comment: Прикольный шаблон спасибо, странно что в C++ по умолчанию такого нету.

Comment: А через перегрузку оператора его нельзя улучшить что бы было так `(a ==== b, c, d)` ну или какие то другие символы?

Comment: Единственное конечно лишняя функция усложняет читаемость кода, не знаю даже буду использовать ее.

Была бы она наглядная как `if (a == b, c, d)` было бы супер
а так даже не поймешь что проверяется ` if (cmp(a, b, c, d))` .

Comment: @sffff Функция лучше всего. Если бы я увидел в коде `a == b, c, d`, моя первая мысль была бы, что программист не знает, как работает `,`. А вторая мысль - "что за дурак догадался перегрузить `,`".

Comment: `a(b == c, d)` - это наглядно??? Вы даже не можете теперь сказать сколько параметров у функции `a`. Это `a(bool)`? Это `a(bool, int)`? Правильный ответ - это кошмар.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу чуть более простой вариант:

```
char a = 1;
char b = 2;
char c = 3;
char d = 5;

auto values = {a, b, c, d};
bool result = std::any_of(values.begin(), values.end(), [&](auto value){return value == 2;});
std::cout << result;
```

Плюсы:

- Каноничное использование STL
- Нет необходимости тащить дополнительную зависимость и добавлять мутные перегрузки операторов
- Можно не просто сравнивать на равенство, но и добавлять более сложные условия типа `value % 2 == 1`
- Можно использовать `std::all_of` или `std::none_of`

Минусы:

- Требует копирования сравниваемых переменных (не критично для примитивных типов, но если надо сравнить что-то дорого копируемое, будет печально)
- Итоговый синтаксис совсем не такой, как спрашивал автор (хотя кмк более явно выражающий намерение программиста)

Answer (score -1):

Вариант с перегрузкой оператора.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename x_LeftValue>
struct
t_Eq
{
    x_LeftValue const & value;
    bool result;

    template<typename x_RightValue>
    explicit t_Eq(x_LeftValue const & left, x_RightValue const & right)
    : value{left}, result{value == right} {}

    explicit operator bool (void) const noexcept { return result; }

    template<typename x_RightValue>
    [[nodiscard]] auto && operator ,(x_RightValue const & right) &&
    {
        result = result or (value == right);
        return ::std::move(*this);
    }
};

template<typename x_LeftValue>
struct
t_With
{
    x_LeftValue const & value;

    explicit t_With(x_LeftValue const & left) noexcept : value{left} {}

    template<typename x_RightValue>
    [[nodiscard]] auto operator ==(x_RightValue const & right) &&
    {
        return t_Eq{value, right};
    }
};

template<typename x_Value>
[[nodiscard]] auto with(x_Value const & value) noexcept
{
    return t_With{value};
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto a{3};
    auto b{5};
    auto c{9};
    auto d{3};
    if (with(a) == b, c, d)
    {
        ::std::cout << "true" << ::std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        ::std::cout << "false" << ::std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAOxmpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSXKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BAUGp6Y4CYRHRLHEJXEl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn6Btpj2RQwNTQQlUbHxibaNza25HQrjA%2BFD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJrtuXo60hACeZ9gmGgCCj08EmCzJBu9nbgQ3yUYrEwx1UAH0QpgqAQAGpiLyYe6vGbELwOV4EMHYACOrxM/isz2OxNBEKhsPhILQDBmpzMADZjgA3SlnQlPEnHGKoTzHYiYBReWgENl4okk96fb6I87/QHMNikgBKeGACAp3hlD3FxMwqi%2BeGQhGOmJxEHBkOhcM1x2ptPMjPo0NIytV6utCNtAntDL5boIy1enJAzNZBKdIv8ABEXfzBcL8RYWTazlHU361ZGo6cCfi088gyS9QajQRjqhAcQmERiFyebRjhAmag8Ohll6aWWGKg9VtkmXE3zMAQNgwh/GRbsLDn8y8dSaPl9qzK/gCgYrwSrMx6tYXiSYAKxWI/d/AKUTEdCHtMH7NMS6oOn0h3lyvVkjHUjmsFb92Ujs%2BoyxD%2Bu2DpgfOiZ7py45CgOuzZnGsHlrWTb/qm6bAZmgZTlBnL8iOxBjiAIAzOgxEsKgTKYBAABUBAIHgCjYeynJ5ni0aigWzySkuPyymuCogha5I7kizwomiIrcWCADqhAIOxLEksJVr/naA6%2BsmCKcXOHJFvq1yliasnyd%2Bloap66lPscEbtt2vaYP2xwhlpiLhuSeY5lYHFcXpxI8dKvxyuuQk/v6om7NqfmnEeh4WKejEXlet7Xsc95EK%2B8TvrW6Hwd%2Bv4WVS3oaUBIFPuB0WQfOeHDqOxk4omrmxv6bE4RBPkvBxbW6QFy5BQJwKkhFUVxXFCXnk0yU3neD7HAA7qZ4I7gBJWhpqdk9qofZSZ1SnEvhdWYnJ9GNWGabdWxvl7AcRwgr8TgopgrBiS8Zj7AwhxeCcvyiAoSjNC9rzhGWLBMOEECBgWubzulj5MImuytXtaWzTEiYHkjUGw7aiYAJyYzDs1XgSiNdcjeBUI2C30RATCgfB6YxC6yAum2UFVdFwYkQQZEoOscFuL8dJmAQqKImYZinOcQvEaRxGuLQOmsR1nJdEo7PQ5zJKyzzxFoJcUuC%2BcwtUGI6sS4bMvc7zCtKySl3RQdhHHBoOkOxwqy0JwB68H4HBaKQqCcILljWMcCjrJsd1vTwpAEJoHurAA1iAB4aPonCSL7CeB5wvAKCA6fx/7HtfjAUDlxASBoJ8dDxOQlA18kdcJMAXBmEkNDCvEBcQDEOcxOETQ3Jwsc12wggAPIMLQI8l6QWCg0Y4jz/g/J1FRBfz3qtSXNsAfA10OfXDEVbEDcHhYDnot4Cwo%2Bl1QBjAAoMJ4Jgc2T/K98yIIIhiOwUgf7yCUGoHOugkgGCMCgaw1h9B4BiAXSAqwKw9C3gAWjQaRVMphQ6WC4P4Y4aCZJiAbEQvUosmCEJkoCdAhhHDIHzl0WoPQXAMHcJ4NoehQjzDKBUPQBQMgCEmH4JIAieiDF4UsTo3R6izGEXoGodQBB9GaBI4YlQxj9HkdUWYajFiVFWBHDYWw9Ci0wNsHgntvbZ3nkHDgqgAAc9I0H0kkMcYAyBkDHHbgAOi4I2EOVhLAulwIQD8ewkjHA8LXegOUY7LF4MXLQyxk6p3Tl7DgWdSB3zTqQP2Ac7H50LnHBOqw4CwCQPzZIlwG4QCbi3SIwJOCOOca49xnjvFmD8bwTA%2BAaytj0PwX%2BohxCAKGcAlQ6h57gNIHNKsyR75WI4D7PJOc7GT0uNUssqBKYtJcW4jxXjfH%2BIgNE5usS6S7C4AkkpJcUmkAQE9LACQIYZ0ybwHJ6d8m8EKbYYpSTE6kBTrkjJuwbEFLzrc5JSyzDgp%2BZCgF9yqLEHSM4SQQA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: Эта лучше выглядит, хотя бы понятно что происходит

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть что возможность перегрузки оператора "запятая" - зло. Скажем `a(b, c)` - это вызов функции с одним аргументом или двумя?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я пока делаю так, `if (f== a || f== b || f== c || f== d)` 
но если будет аргументов 100 я буду использовать функцию, еще и цикл туда добавлю, думаю будет круто.


Не думайте что я прям пихаю такие функции куда попало, просто это как решение нормальный пример к моему вопросу, а использовать его или нет, это дело выбора.

Comment: Сто регулярных аргументов - повод перейти на контейнер или список инициализации.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy хорошая мысль кстати

Answer (score -1):

Списки инициализации обеспечивают достаточно компактный синтаксис:

```
template<class T>
bool in(const T &x, std::initializer_list<T> c) {
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), x) != c.end();
}

...
    char A1 = 1, B2 = 2, C3 = 3;

    char function = ...;
    if (in(function, {A1, B2, C3})) {
        ...
    }
...
```

У оптимизатора есть возможность развернуть код в последовательность:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

template<class T>
bool in(const T &x, std::initializer_list<T> c) {
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), x) != c.end();
}

bool check(char function) {
    char A1 = 1, B2 = 2, C3 = 3;
    return in(function, {A1, B2, C3});
}
```

Цикла в ассемблере нет, а есть три сравнения с тремя константами:

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -S temp.cpp
> $ cat temp.s
>
>   .file   "temp.cpp"
>   .text
>   .p2align 4
>   .globl  _Z5checkc
>   .type   _Z5checkc, @function
> _Z5checkc:
> .LFB3008:
>   .cfi_startproc
>   movl    $1, %eax
>   cmpb    $1, %dil
>   je  .L1
>   cmpb    $2, %dil
>   je  .L1
>   cmpb    $3, %dil
>   sete    %al
> .L1:
>   ret
>   .cfi_endproc
> .LFE3008:
>   .size   _Z5checkc, .-_Z5checkc
>   .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04) 9.4.0"
>   .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
> ```

Comment: Ух ты, это лучший вариант с учетом что в ассемблере мало кода

Comment: В этом весь C++: синтаксис кривенький, но есть возможно довести оптимизацию до производительности ассемблера (ну почти всегда, у ассемблера есть ещё в запасе трюки).

Comment: Реализовано тоже круто очень удобный, еще и количество аргументов может быть сколько угодно.

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас точно сравнение идёт байтовое и без проверки на нуль, то самый простой способ это использовать функцию поиска буквы в строке.

Создаёте массив байт с завершающим нулевым

```
char arr [ ] = { A1 , B2 , C3 , D4 , E5 , 0 } ;
```

и вызываете функцию `strchr` , она возвращает указатель на найденные байт или **nullptr**.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstring>
int main(){
    char f = 2 ;
    char A1 = 1, B2 = 2, C3 = 3, D4 = 4, E5=5;
    char arr [ ] = { A1 , B2 , C3 , D4 , E5 , 0 } ;
    if ( strchr ( arr , f ) )
      std::cout<<(int)f<<" присутствует в массиве"<<std::endl;
    else
      std::cout<<(int)f<<" не найден в массиве"<<std::endl;
}
```